# AddIPAddress not taking immediate effect

Tags: winapi, networking

I'm seeing on Windows Server 2008 that even if `AddIPAddress` succeeds, I cannot bind immediately after a socket to the requested address: I get `WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL`, and I have to wait at least several seconds to make a successful bind. Even if I hack in a `system("netsh in ip add address ...")` I get the same problem, so it's a system wide effect.

Does anyone know more about this? Is there a way to "atomically" add an ip address to an interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes times to update the IP tables with the new IP and propagate that through the system. You will just have to wait for it to finish.  Call `bind()` in a loop until it stop reporting `WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL`, or until a timeout of your choosing elapses.